# Unable to invoke headless chrome driver through Selenium webdriver(Java) in Heroku

Tags: java, google-chrome, heroku, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm facing an issue while invoking headless chrome in heroku environment and working perfect in WINDOWS(local machine).

Error:

```
 2018-02-07T05:37:22.412428+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.appirio.sd.TestScript` 2018-02-07T05:37:24.211467+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.

 2018-02-07T05:37:24.219616+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.381460+00:00 app[web.1]: Invoke Browser
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.503816+00:00 app[web.1]: Path: /app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.503854+00:00 app[web.1]: Driver Path: agent//chromedriver
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.650636+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /app/agent/chromedriver
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.650644+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:534)
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.650650+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.650647+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:140)
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.650655+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.650649+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:131)
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.650653+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.650657+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.650658+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.650660+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.appirio.commands.Selenium.launchBrowser(Selenium.java:42)
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.650663+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.appirio.sd.TestScript.main(TestScript.java:12)
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.733915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
 2018-02-07T05:37:24.717297+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Code snip:

```
    public WebDriver launchBrowser(){
    String driverPath="";
    if(getOS().equals(OS.WINDOWS)){
        driverPath="agent//chromedriver.exe";
    }else if(getOS().equals(OS.LINUX)){
        driverPath="agent//chromedriver";
    }   

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
    if(getOS().equals(OS.LINUX)){
        try{   //GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN
            String binaryPath=EnvironmentUtils.getProcEnvironment().get("GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM");
            System.out.println("Path: "+binaryPath);
            options.setBinary(binaryPath);     
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");       
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }      

    System.out.println("Driver Path: "+driverPath);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);

    return driver;
}
```

Heroku is Linux environment so, few conditions specifically added for Linux env.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prior & after posting this question, invested ample time to resolve this issue. I'm very much happy to say that got succeed.

Solution:

I have specified driver path(in script) & added driver build pack in heroku env. Driver path was creating the problem. So just removed the below like of code for heroku env & added only for windows

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
```

Due to this, code looks like

```
public WebDriver launchBrowser(){
String driverPath="";
if(getOS().equals(OS.WINDOWS)){
    driverPath="agent//chromedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
}  

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
if(getOS().equals(OS.LINUX)){
    try{   //GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN
        String binaryPath=EnvironmentUtils.getProcEnvironment().get("GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM");
        System.out.println("Path: "+binaryPath);
        options.setBinary(binaryPath);     
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");       
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}    

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);

return driver;
}
```

Just to summarized entire approach to setup "selenium webdriver java script which invokes Headless chrome" in Heroku:

> Add below buildpacks to hero app
>
> > heroku/java
> >
> > https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
> >
> > https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
>
> Deploy the code in heroku app

Thanks everyone!

Commands to Add the build packs.

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/java
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
```